# An old plugin self-made stoped sending mail

Tags: plugins, wp-mail

I have a old plugin running that let people pick products and then sends a mail to the store that is selected. But for a while now it has stoped sending the mails. I guess something in the code is out of date or something?

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: BreadForm
    Description: 
    Version: 
    Author: 
    Author URI: 
*/

if (!class_exists("BreadFormPlugin")) {
    class BreadFormPlugin
    {
        protected $fromEmail = "info@something.com";

        protected $fromName = "something";

        function BreadFormPlugin()
        {
            $this->__construct();
        }

        function __construct()
        {
            add_shortcode('breadform', array($this, 'shortcode_breadform'));
        }

        function getItems()
        {
            // Price should be entered in "cents"
            $items = array(
                array("name" => "Product 1", "price" => 1050),
                array("name" => "Product 2", "price" => 525),
            );

            $new_array = array();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $item["hash"] = md5($item["name"]);
                $new_array[md5($item["name"])] = $item;
            }

            return $new_array;
        }

        function getShops()
        {
            $shops = array(
                array("name" => "store 1", "email" => "store1@something.com"),
                array("name" => "store 2", "email" => "store2@something.com"),
            );

            $new_array = array();
            foreach ($shops as $shop) {
                $shop["hash"] = md5($shop["name"]);
                $new_array[md5($shop["name"])] = $shop;
            }

            return $new_array;

        }

        function enqueue_scripts()
        {
            wp_register_script('breadformScript', plugins_url('/breadform.js', __FILE__), array("jquery"), '1.0');
            wp_register_script('styleSelect', plugins_url('/jquery.styleSelect.min.js', __FILE__), array("jquery"), '1.0');
            wp_register_script('jscrollpane', plugins_url('/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js', __FILE__), array("jquery"), '1.0');
            wp_register_script('mousewheel', plugins_url('/jscrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js', __FILE__), array("jquery"), '1.0');

            wp_enqueue_script('breadformScript');
            wp_enqueue_script('styleSelect');
            wp_enqueue_script('jscrollpane');
            wp_enqueue_script('mousewheel');

            wp_register_style('breadformStyle', plugins_url('/breadform.css', __FILE__), false, '1.01', 'all');
            wp_register_style('jscrollpaneStyle', plugins_url('/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0', 'all');

            wp_enqueue_style('breadformStyle');
            wp_enqueue_style('jscrollpaneStyle');

            // declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
            wp_localize_script('breadformScript', 'BreadForm', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

        }

        function shortcode_breadform()
        {

            $shops = $this->getShops();
            $items = $this->getItems();

            $output = '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var breadformItems = ' . json_encode($items) . ';
            </script>
            <div id="breadformForm">
                <div id="breadformOrderRow">
                    <div id="breadformBoxItem">
                    <select name="breadformItem" id="breadformItem" class="breadformSelect">
                        <option value="">Bread</option>
                        ';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . md5($item['name']) . '">' . $item['name'] . ' - ' . number_format(($item['price'] / 100), 2, ',', ' ') . ' GBP</option>';
            }
            $output .= '
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="breadformBoxQty">
                    <select name="breadformQty" id="breadformQty" class="breadformSelectShort">
                        <option value="1">QTY</option>
                        ';
            for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . ' pcs</option>';
            }
            $output .= '

                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="breadformAdd">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div id="breadformCart">
                    <div id="breadformCartTop">
                        <div id="breadformSummary"><div id="breadformTitle">Order</div><div id="breadformAmountTitle">Sum:</div><div id="breadformAmount">0 GBP</div><br class="clear: both;"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="breadformCartMain"><div id="breadformLoader"></div><div id="breadformCartContent"></div></div>
                    <div id="breadformCartBottom"></div>
                </div>
<div id="breadformShop">
                    <select name="breadformSelectedShop" id="breadformSelectedShop" class="breadformSelect">
                        <option value="">Shop</option>
                        ';
            foreach ($shops as $shop) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . md5($shop['name']) . '">' . $shop['name'] . '</option>';
            }
            $output .= '
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="breadformDateRow">
                    <div id="breadformBoxDate">
                    <select name="breadformDate" id="breadformDate" class="breadformSelect">
                        <option value="">Date for pickup</option>

                        ';
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . date('Ymd',time()+($i*86400)) . '">'.date_i18n('l, d F',time()+($i*86400)).'</option>';
            }
            $output .= '
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="breadformBoxTime">
                    <select name="breadformTime" id="breadformTime" class="breadformSelectShort">
                        <option value="">Time</option>
                        ';
            for ($i = 8; $i <= 18; $i++) {
                $output .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':00</option>';
            }
            $output .= '

                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="breadformCustomer">

                    <label for="breadformName">Name:</label>
                    <input type="breadformName" id="breadformName" value="" class="breadformInput noFocus"/>

                    <label for="breadformPhone">Phone:</label>
                    <input type="breadformPhone" id="breadformPhone" value="" class="breadformInput noFocus"/>

                    <label for="breadformEmail">E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="breadformEmail" id="breadformEmail" value="" class="breadformInput noFocus" />

                    <label for="breadformMessage">Message:</label>
                    <textarea name="breadformMessage" id="breadformMessage" class="noFocus"></textarea>

                    <div id="breadformSubmit" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;"></div><div id="breadformSubmitLoading"></div>
                </div>

            </div><div id="breadformSuccess"><h1>Thanks for ordering</h1></div>';
            return $output;
        }

        function ajax_callback()
        {
            global $BreadFormPlugin;
            $shops = $BreadFormPlugin->getShops();
            $items = $BreadFormPlugin->getItems();
            $message = "";
            if (isset($_SESSION['breadform_cart']) === false) {
                $_SESSION['breadform_cart'] = array(
                    'total' => 0,
                    'items' => array()
                );
            }


            if ($_POST['cart_action'] == "add") {
                if (array_key_exists($_POST['cart_item'], $items)) {
                    if (array_key_exists($_POST['cart_item'], $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'])) {
                        $new_qty = intval($_POST['cart_item_qty']) + intval($_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']]['qty']);
                        $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']] = array(
                            'hash' => $items[$_POST['cart_item']]['hash'],
                            'item' => $items[$_POST['cart_item']]['name'],
                            'qty' => $new_qty,
                            'total' => (intval($items[$_POST['cart_item']]['price']) * $new_qty),
                        );
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']] = array(
                            'hash' => $items[$_POST['cart_item']]['hash'],
                            'item' => $items[$_POST['cart_item']]['name'],
                            'qty' => intval($_POST['cart_item_qty']),
                            'total' => (intval($items[$_POST['cart_item']]['price']) * intval($_POST['cart_item_qty'])),
                        );
                    }
                    $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']]['pretty_qty'] = $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']]['qty'] . " pcs";
                    $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']]['pretty_total'] = number_format(($_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']]['total'] / 100), 2, ',', ' ') . " GBP";
                }
            } elseif ($_POST['cart_action'] == "delete") {
                if (array_key_exists($_POST['cart_item'], $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'])) {
                    unset($_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'][$_POST['cart_item']]);
                }

            } elseif ($_POST['cart_action'] == "order") {
                $senderName = $_POST['senderName'];
                $senderPhone = $_POST['senderPhone'];
                $senderEmail = $_POST['senderEmail'];
                $senderMessage = $_POST['senderMessage'];
                $selectedShop = $_POST['selectedShop'];
                $selectedDate = intval($_POST['selectedDate']);
                $selectedTime = intval($_POST['selectedTime']);


                if (strlen($senderName) < 3) {
                    $message = "Please fill in you name.";
                }
                if (is_email($senderEmail) == false) {
                    $message = "Please check the e-mail.";
                }


                if ($selectedTime < 4 || $selectedTime > 23) {
                    $message = "Something is wrong with the selected time";
                }

                if ($selectedDate < 20120101) {
                    $message = "Something is wrong with the date".$selectedDate;
                }


                if (array_key_exists($selectedShop, $shops) == FALSE) {
                    $message = "No shop is selected";
                }

                if (count($_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items']) < 1) {
                    $message = "You need to add something first.";
                }


                // Successful order
                if ($message == "") {

                    // Prepare cart
                    $cartMessage = "";
                    foreach ($_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'] as $item) {
                        $cartMessage .= $item['pretty_qty']."\t\t".$item['item']." - ".$item['pretty_total']."\n";
                    }
                    $cartMessage .= "\nTotal: ".$_SESSION['breadform_cart']['total'];


                    // Start preparing order e-mail (to the store)
                    $orderMessage = "


Name: ".$senderName."
Phone: ".$senderPhone."
Mail: ".$senderEmail."
Message: ".$senderMessage."
For collection: ".$selectedDate." - ".str_pad($selectedTime, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":00



Order:

".$cartMessage;



                    // Start preparing  e-mail (to the store)
                    $confirmationMessage = " 
We have  received your order.

Namne: ".$senderName."
Phone: ".$senderPhone."
E-mail: ".$senderEmail."
Message: ".$senderMessage."
For collection: ".$selectedDate." - ".str_pad($selectedTime, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":00

Your order:

".$cartMessage."

---

";

                    $headers = 'From: '.$senderEmail.' <'.$senderName.'>' . "\r\n";

                    // Send email to store
                    wp_mail($shops[$selectedShop]['email'], 'Order from webpage', $orderMessage, $headers);

                    // Send email to customer
                    // wp_mail($senderEmail, 'Tack för din beställning', $confirmationMessage, $headers);

                    $message = "success";

                    $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'] = array();
                    $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['total'] = 0;

                }


            } elseif ($_POST['cart_action'] == "clear") {
                $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'] = array();
                $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['total'] = 0;
            }


            $total_amount = 0;
            // summarize total amount
            foreach ($_SESSION['breadform_cart']['items'] as $item) {
                $total_amount += $item['total'];
            }

            $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['message'] = $message;
            $_SESSION['breadform_cart']['total'] = number_format(($total_amount / 100), 2, ',', ' ') . " GBP";
            echo json_encode($_SESSION['breadform_cart']);
            die(); // this is required to return a proper result
        }

    }

}

if (class_exists("BreadFormPlugin")) {
    $BreadFormPlugin = new BreadFormPlugin();
}

//Actions and Filters
if (isset($BreadFormPlugin)) {
    //Actions
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array("BreadFormPlugin", 'enqueue_scripts'));

    add_action('wp_ajax_breadform', array("BreadFormPlugin", 'ajax_callback'));
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_breadform', array("BreadFormPlugin", 'ajax_callback'));

    //Filters
}

if (!session_id()) {
    add_action('init', 'session_start');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many E-Mail-Hosters changed their rules to prevent spam. Often times, E-Mails that have one domain name in their "from"-Tag and come from a server with a different domain are rejected. So my guess is, maybe the emails are still sent, but not received.

You can check this by changing this line:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$senderEmail.' <'.$senderName.'>' . "\r\n";
```

to something like this:

```
$my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$headers = 'From: orders@'.$my_domain."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$senderEmail."\r\n";
```

and check if the e-mails are sent and received correctly now.
(By setting the Reply-To Header, the correct Address is inserted when clicking on "Reply" in the Mail Client.)