# Contact form code not working. Need help!

Tags: shortcode, forms

I am using the below contact from code in the WordPress by creating shortcode. When i submit the form it shows success message but didn't get any email in inbox or spam. Can anybody please help.

```
function contactform_func( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'to_email' => '',
    'title' => 'Contact enquiry - '.get_bloginfo('url'),
), $atts );

$cform = "<div class=\"main-form-area\" id=\"contactform_main\">";

$cerr = array();
if( isset($_POST['c_submit']) && $_POST['c_submit']=='Submit' ){
    $name           = trim( $_POST['c_name'] );
    $email          = trim( $_POST['c_email'] );
    $phone          = trim( $_POST['c_phone'] );
    $website        = trim( $_POST['c_website'] );
    $comments       = trim( $_POST['c_comments'] );
    $captcha        = trim( $_POST['c_captcha'] );
    $captcha_cnf    = trim( $_POST['c_captcha_confirm'] );

    if( !$name )
        $cerr['name'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    if( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) 
        $cerr['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email.';
    if( !$phone )
        $cerr['phone'] = 'Please enter your phone number.';
    if( !$comments )
        $cerr['comments'] = 'Please enter your question / comments.';
    if( !$captcha || (md5($captcha) != $captcha_cnf) )
        $cerr['captcha'] = 'Please enter the correct answer.';

    if( count($cerr) == 0 ){
        $subject = $atts['title'];
        $headers = "From: ".$name." <" . strip_tags($email) . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

        $message = '<html><body>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>Name: </td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Email: </td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Phone: </td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Website: </td><td>'.$website.'</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Comments: </td><td>'.$comments.'</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>';
        mail( $atts['to_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
        $cform .= '<div class="success_msg">Thank you! A representative will get back to you very shortly.</div>';
        unset( $name, $email, $phone, $website, $comments, $captcha );
    }else{
        $cform .= '<div class="error_msg">';
        $cform .= implode('<br />',$cerr);
        $cform .= '</div>';
    }
}

$capNum1    = rand(1,4);
$capNum2    = rand(1,5);
$capSum     = $capNum1 + $capNum2;
$sumStr     = $capNum1." + ".$capNum2 ." = ";

$cform .= "<form name=\"contactform\" action=\"#contactform_main\" method=\"post\">
        <p class=\"left\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"c_name\" value=\"". ( ( empty($name) == false ) ? $name : "" ) ."\" placeholder=\"Name\" /></p>
        <p class=\"right\"><input type=\"email\" name=\"c_email\" value=\"". ( ( empty($email) == false ) ? $email : "" ) ."\" placeholder=\"Email\" /></p><div class=\"clear\"></div>
        <p class=\"left\"><input type=\"tel\" name=\"c_phone\" value=\"". ( ( empty($phone) == false ) ? $phone : "" ) ."\" placeholder=\"Phone\" /></p>
        <p class=\"right\"><input type=\"url\" name=\"c_website\" value=\"". ( ( empty($website) == false ) ? $website : "" ) ."\" placeholder=\"Website with prefix http://\" /></p><div class=\"clear\"></div>
        <p><textarea name=\"c_comments\" placeholder=\"Message\">". ( ( empty($comments) == false ) ? $comments : "" ) ."</textarea></p>";
$cform .= "<br /><p class=\"left\">$sumStr<input style=\"width:200px;\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Captcha\" value=\"". ( ( empty($captcha) == false ) ? $captcha : "" ) ."\" name=\"c_captcha\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"c_captcha_confirm\" value=\"". md5($capSum)."\"></p><div class=\"clear\"></div>";
$cform .= "<p class=\"sub\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"c_submit\" value=\"Submit\" /></p>
    </form>
</div>";
return $cform;} add_shortcode( 'contactform', 'contactform_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my Answer for ["An old plugin self-made stoped sending mail"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/279342/56587):

Many E-Mail-Hosters changed their rules to prevent spam. Often times, E-Mails that have one domain name in their "from"-Tag and come from a server with a different domain are rejected. So my guess is, maybe the emails are still sent, but not received.

You can check this by changing this line:

```
$headers = "From: ".$name." <" . strip_tags($email) . ">\r\n";
```

to something like this:

```
$my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$headers = 'From: orders@'.$my_domain."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$senderEmail."\r\n";
```

and check if the e-mails are sent and received correctly now. (By setting the Reply-To Header, the correct Address is inserted when clicking on "Reply" in the Mail Client.)

Comment: I have replace the line as you suggest but it still shows the success message on frontend but email not received :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure the `mail()` function is successful, try change this part:

```
$result = mail( $atts['to_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
if($result){
    $cform .= '<div class="success_msg">Thank you! A representative will get back to you very shortly.</div>';
}
```

Then if you still see the success message, you know it is something else.

Comment: I did the changes now after fill up the form it does not shows the success message. Does that mean mail function is not working properly ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Before the $result line,  can you echo the contents of `$atts['to_email']`?  Just to make sure that you are passing the to value through your shortcode.

Comment: How are you writing the shortcode when you are using it on the site?

Comment: I am using the shortcode like this 
[contactform to_email="skyf062@gmail.com" title="Contact Form"]
Also i have notice that this problem  is happen with the latest version of WordPress. Before that it was working fine. 
Can you please provide me any solutions. 
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Right before the mail function add this code: `echo $atts['to_email']; exit();` This way we can make sure we know what is being given to the `to` in the mail function.

Comment: After doing this and submitting form it shows the email id which is pass through the shortcode parameter.
After form submission it shows skyf062@gmail.com

Comment: Need some help ?

Comment: Can you echo out each of the variables that you are inserting into the mail() function and post them here?

Comment: `echo $atts['to_email']; exit();

   $result = mail( $atts['to_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);

   if($result){

    $cform .= '<div class="success_msg">Thank you! A representative will get back to you very shortly.</div>';

}`

Comment: Sorry,  what are the actual values for: `$subject`, `$message`, `$headers`?

Comment: while echo
$atts['to_email'] = email id, 
$subject =  Contact Form, 
$message = values of all fields, 
$headers =  From: orders@domainname.com Reply-To: MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: It looks like the problem lies with `$atts['to_email']` as this should echo out an email address to send the email to.  This should be your email address for testing.  `email id` is not a valid email address so the mail function is failing.  Can you try hard coding the mail() function.
`mail('your@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers)`

Comment: Yes the `$atts['to_email']` shows the email id i have used to get the mails but still did not received the emaiils.

Comment: The `email id` must be in the format `email@address.com` it cannot be an email id.

Comment: Yes. thats what i am saying it shows skyf062@gmail.com

Comment: When i echo $atts['to_email'] it shows `skyf062@gmail.com`.

Comment: Did you check your spam folder in your email?

Comment: Yes i did check but got no mail.

Comment: Does your server have the mail() set to work? try:
`<?php
if ( function_exists( 'mail' ) )
{
    echo 'mail() is available';
}
else
{
    echo 'mail() has been disabled';
}
?>`

Comment: Also add this at the top of your script:

`ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );`

Comment: mail () is available
no any error found.

Comment: I notice that this issue was started with the latest version of WordPress. I use the same form in the older version and it was worked.